# Get the SyntaxNode given the linenumber in a SyntaxTree

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to get the SyntaxNode of a line given the location(lineNumber). The code below should be self-explanatory, but let me know of any questions.

```
static void Main()
        {
            string codeSnippet = @"using System;
                                        class Program
                                        {
                                            static void Main(string[] args)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
                                            }
                                        }";

            SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(codeSnippet);
            string[] lines = codeSnippet.Split('\n');
            SyntaxNode node = GetNode(tree, 6); //How??
        }

        static SyntaxNode GetNode(SyntaxTree tree,int lineNumber)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            // *** What I did ***
            //Calculted length from using System... to Main(string[] args) and named it (totalSpan)
            //Calculated length of the line(lineNumber) Console.Writeline("Helllo...."); and named it (lineSpan)
            //Created a textspan : TextSpan span = new TextSpan(totalSpan, lineSpan);
            //Was able to get back the text of the line : tree.GetLocation(span);
            //But how to get the SyntaxNode corresponding to that line??
        }
```

Comment: What if there is no node at that line? What if there is more than one?

Comment: @svick I am assuming ideal case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, to get `TextSpan` based on a line number, you can use the indexer of `Lines` of the `SourceText` returned by `GetText()` (but careful, it counts lines from 0).

Then, to get all nodes that intersect that span, you can use an overload of `DescendantNodes()`.

Finally, you filter that list to get the first node that is contained fully in that line.

In code:

```
static SyntaxNode GetNode(SyntaxTree tree, int lineNumber)
{
    var lineSpan = tree.GetText().Lines[lineNumber - 1].Span;
    return tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes(lineSpan)
        .First(n => lineSpan.Contains(n.Span));
}
```

If there is no node on that line, this will throw an exception. If there is more than one, it will return the first one.

Comment: What dll contains the GetLineFromLineNumber?

Comment: @johnny5 This answer is ancient, there is no `GetLineFromLineNumber` in the current version of Roslyn. I have updated the answer to code that works for me now.

Comment: @svick How do you extract the text on that line? for example " class Program" on line 2 ?

Comment: @theanimashaun You can use [the overload of `SourceText.ToString()` that takes a `TextSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.text.sourcetext.tostring?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Text_SourceText_ToString_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Text_TextSpan_): `tree.GetText().ToString(lineSpan)`.